# tf.reshape is not working in the cases where you are adding an extra dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

According to the tensorflow website, tf.reshape takes a tensor of a certain shape and maps it to a tensor of another shape. I want to map a tensor of size [600, 64] to a tensor of size [-1, 8, 8, 1] (in which the dimension at the -1 position is 600). This doesn't seem to be working though.

I am running this on tensorflow on python 3.6 and although it reshapes to something like [-1, 8, 8], it doesn't reshape to [-1, 8, 8, 1]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

# preprocessing method needed
    def flatten(array):
        temp = []
        for j in array:
            temp.extend(j)
        return temp

# preprocess the data
digits = datasets.load_digits()
images = digits.images
images = [flatten(i) for i in images]
labels = digits.target
labels = LabelBinarizer().fit_transform(labels)

# the stats needed
width = 8
height = 8
alpha = 0.1
num_labels = 10
kernel_length = 3
batch_size = 10
channels = 1

# the tensorflow placeholders and reshaping
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, width * height * channels])

# AND NOW HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR STARTS
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, num_labels])
X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 8, 8, 1])

# the convolutional model
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(X, filters = 32, kernel_size = [kernel_length,  kernel_length])
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(conv1, filters = 64, kernel_size = [2, 2])
flatten = tf.reshape(X, [-1, 1])
dense1 = tf.layers.dense(flatten, units=50, activation = tf.nn.relu)
y_pred = tf.layers.dense(dense1, units=num_labels, activation = tf.nn.softmax)

# the loss and training functions
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred)
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(alpha).minimize(loss)

# initializing the variables and the tf.session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# running the session
for i in range(batch_size):
    _, lossVal = sess.run((train, loss), feed_dict = {X:images[:600], y_true: labels[:600]})
    print(lossVal)
```

I keep on getting this error:
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (600, 64) for Tensor 'Reshape:0', which has shape '(?, 8, 8, 1)'
And I feel like that should not be the case since 8 * 8 * 1 does equal 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`images[:600]`'s shape is `(600, 64)`, which does not correspond to the placeholder expected shape, `(None, 8, 8, 1)`.

Either reshape your data or change the shape of the placeholder.

Note that the fact that you originally defined the placeholder shape to be `(None, 64)` is inconsequential as you reshape it a few lines later.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the statement: "Note that the fact that you originally defined the placeholder shape to be (None, 64) is inconsequential as you reshape it a few lines later." Does that mean tensorflow is going to expect an input with dimensions (None, 8, 8, 1)  even though we said the input should be (None, 64) simply because tensorflow takes the reshape into consideration (during the creation of the computational graph) and then requests dimensions that fit into that requirement?

Comment: Precisely. When you use `feed_dict={X:...}`, `X` is a placeholder of shape `(None, 8, 8, 1)`. If you wish to feed an array of shape `(600, 64)` and reshape it to `(None, 8, 8, 1)`, do not overwrite `X` with `X = tf.reshape(...)` but use something like `X_reshape = tf.reshape(...)`.